# Server timeout from outside, network unreachable from inside

Tags: linux, linode

I have a Linode instance (Debian 7.4) running Apache server (2.2.22) that I mostly use for just storing files that I can then easily link to from elsewhere. I've additionally purchased a domain from GoDaddy to make such links easier. I noticed today that an image I'm storing on this server and linked to elsewhere was displaying as a broken link.

Attempting to access myserver.com in my browser results in ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. However, apache2 is running when I check it from the Lish console (Linode's web console).

Attempting to access my instance via ssh in an actual terminal results in `ssh: connect to host myserver.com port 22: Connection timed out`. However, sshd is running when I check it from Lish. (The same happens trying to ssh via IP.)

Attempting to ping my server in an actual terminal (by domain or IP) results in 100% packet loss. Attempting to ping localhost from the Lish console results in 0% packet loss (of course), but attempting to ping the server's IP (or any IP other than 127.0.0.1) from Lish results in `connect: Network is unreachable`.

From within Lish, `curl` on localhost or getting the status from apache2 reports a 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable). `curl` on any IP address I've tried other than 127.0.0.1 results in `curl: (7) Failed to connect to X.X.X.X: Network is unreachable`. `curl` on any domain results in `curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'example.com'`.

I can't recall making any changes to the Linode's configuration or the server settings since the last time I specifically successfully linked something on the server to someone (sharing a gzipped tarball with a friend, May 10 this year), but clearly something is wrong, and I'm not sure what the culprit might be.

Neither restarting Apache nor restarting the Linode instance fixed the issue. I've tried a few changes suggested by Google searching, including adding my domain to the hosts file and adding my domain as a `ServerName` to the Apache config, but none of the relatively trivial fixes I've tried have worked, and I'm not a Linux guru to feel confident in what I'm doing when it comes to network configuration stuff.

Comment: Is there any firewall setup somewhere? Sounds like the VM just doesnt have network access or it is being blocked via some sort of firewall.

Comment: @Analog all the iptables have no rules and an ACCEPT policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacted Linode support about the issue, and their first suggestion was to flip the auto-configure networking option on the server to enabled and reboot. This is apparently an option that Linode created at some point after I created my account (the account-wide version of the option marks the "disabled" setting as being "legacy"), which explains it being disabled, and when enabled, at boot time, Linode automatically configures network settings on the server.

While I'm still not certain what caused the issue in the first place, this automatic configuration did solve my problem.